# vim how to unabbreviate

Tags: vim

I have abbreviated main to '#include.....', I was looking to unabbreviate it for one vim session, and tried the following

```
:una main
```

I get error 'E24: No such abbreviation'. The problem is, it's expanding the main in this command also. When I check the history, it shows

```
:una #include<stdio.h>
```

which proves that it has expanded the abbreviation.

I hope it's clear. Is there any way to solve this issue?
I know `abc` will clear all abbreviations, but I am only looking to unabbreviate one abbreviation.

I am using this version:

```
$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4
```

Comment: I have the same `vim` version and I can't reproduce this behavior. My command history shows (like yours) that the abbreviation was expanded with `una` but it is disabled after I enter the command.

Comment: Could it be that you're typing `:una main ` followed by a space? In other words, are you causing the abbreviation to be expanded before entering the command?

Comment: @Joseph I tried with space and direct enter both, give same behaviour

Comment: Also note, if you abbreviate at the buffer level, you have to unabbreviate at the buffer level as well, e.g. `iuna <buffer> main`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert `CTRL-V` somewhere in the abbreviation to avoid the abbreviation occur. After typing `:una ma`, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> twice, then typ `in`, your command mode now look like this:

```
:una ma^Vin
```

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and the abbreviation was gone.

---

It's better if you only define abbreviation in which mode you want to operate. In your case, using `iab` to make `main` only work in insert mode. You won't face the same problem when you un-abbreviate it in command mode.

Comment: `iab` --> perfectly worked :)